Plotting paired data
I am trying to use seaborn's object-oriented interface to make a plot of paired data where each pair is connected by a line segment. I want a single subplot in the final plot to look like this:

The closest I can get is the following:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Treated':['N']*10+['Y']*10,
                  'Treatment':['A']*20,
                  'value':np.random.random(20),
                    'Individual': [str(i) for i in list(range(10))+list(range(10))],
                'Genotype':(['WT']*5+['M1']*5)*2
                                                       
                                                       
})


p=(
    so.Plot(df,
            x= 'Treatment',y='value',
            # color='Individual',
            color='Genotype',
            fill='Treated',
           )
    
    .add(so.Dot(),so.Dodge(by=['fill']),so.Jitter(width=.00,seed=0),group = "Individual",
         legend=True)
    .add(so.Line(),so.Dodge(by=['fill']),so.Jitter(width=.00,seed=0),legend=None,group = "Individual")
    
    .scale(
        fill =so.Nominal(['N','Y'],order = ["N","Y"]),
    )
)
p.show()
            

Seaborn output:

Adding the group="Individual" introduces an additional and unwanted dodge into the plot.  Without it, the lines do not connect the pairs of points but connect all points to each other.
I'm looking for a way to pass a different variable into Lines, override the automatic dodging effect of group or an entirely different way.

There may be a more elegant answer, but individual lines can be added manually as follows.
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import seaborn.objects as so
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Treated':['N']*10+['Y']*10,
                  'Treatment':['A']*20,
                  'value':np.random.random(20),
                    'Individual': [str(i) for i in list(range(10))+list(range(10))],
                'Genotype':(['WT']*5+['M1']*5)*2
                                                       
                                                       
})


p=(
    so.Plot(df,
            x= 'Treatment',y='value',
            # color='Individual',
            color='Genotype',
            fill='Treated',
           )
    
    .add(so.Dot(),so.Dodge(by=['fill']),so.Jitter(width=.05,seed=0),
         legend=True)
    .scale(
        fill =so.Nominal(['N','Y'],order = ["N","Y"]),
    )
    
)

####### add lines for each individual #######
for i in df['Individual'].unique():
    p = p.add(so.Line(pointsize=0),so.Dodge(by=['fill']),so.Jitter(width=.05,seed=0)legend=None,data=df[df['Individual']==i])
####### add lines for each individual #######
p.show()


